# How do I change my Application name

Tags: android

I would like to make a slight change to my application's name. I read that it can work if both applications are signed with the same signature and is given the same userId then they can share information and I can migrate the original application's information to the new one. It is very important that the user gets the notification to upgrade. Will the user receive the update to upgrade if its done this way?

Comment: As Barry mentioned it it is no problem, simply change it in strings :)

Answer (score 2):

Your users will still get the upgrade, as long as you don't change the top level java package name.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We want to change the name of the app. It's a small change: a capital X to a lower case x.

Comment: Yep - that'll be fine. Users will still get the upgrade.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if you're satisfied your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the actual name (human readable) or the application package? You can change the name, description, etc. at any time (though it might be confusing for existing users). On the other hand, you cannot change the package name, you need to publish a new app. Unless the current app already has the `sharedUserId`, set you cannot really use that option: setting it will change the UID and the application won't be able to see its own files. Two solutions to this:

- export the data in some shared format (XML, CSV, JSON, etc.)
- write a content provider and use a signature permission to make sure only your apps can read from it.

Comment: Thanks! I will pass this on to the developer. ;)

Comment: Get your developers on SO instead :)